# make bouncing turtle with python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am a beginner with python and I wrote this code to make bouncing ball with python turtle it works but have some errors like the ball disappearing

```
import turtle
turtle.shape("circle")
xdir = 1
x = 1
y = 1
ydir = 1
while True:
     x = x + 3 * xdir
     y = y + 3 * ydir
    turtle.goto(x , y)
    if x >= turtle.window_width():
        xdir = -1
    if x <= -turtle.window_width():
        xdir = 1
    if y >= turtle.window_height():
        ydir = -1
    if y <= -turtle.window_height():
        ydir = 1
    turtle.penup()
turtle.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `window_width()/2` and `window_height()/2` to keep inside window.

ie.

```
if x >= turtle.window_width()/2:
    xdir = -1
if x <= -turtle.window_width()/2:
    xdir = 1
if y >= turtle.window_height()/2:
    ydir = -1
if y <= -turtle.window_height()/2:
    ydir = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Although your approach to the problem works (my rework):

```
import turtle

turtle.shape("circle")
turtle.penup()

x, y = 0, 0
xdir, ydir = 3, 3
xlimit, ylimit = turtle.window_width() / 2, turtle.window_height() / 2

while True:
    x = x + xdir
    y = y + ydir

    if not -xlimit < x < xlimit:
        xdir = -xdir
    if not -ylimit < y < ylimit:
        ydir = -ydir

    turtle.goto(x, y)

turtle.mainloop()
```

In the long run, it's the wrong approach to take.  In this case, due to the infinite loop `while True`, the `mainloop()` method is never called so no other turtle event handlers are active.  For example, if we wanted to use `exitonclick()` instead of `mainloop()`, it wouldn't work.  Instead consider:

```
import turtle

turtle.shape("circle")
turtle.penup()

x, y = 0, 0
xdir, ydir = 3, 3
xlimit, ylimit = turtle.window_width() / 2, turtle.window_height() / 2

def move():
    global x, y, xdir, ydir

    x = x + xdir
    y = y + ydir

    if not -xlimit < x < xlimit:
        xdir = -xdir
    if not -ylimit < y < ylimit:
        ydir = -ydir

    turtle.goto(x, y)

    turtle.ontimer(move, 5)

turtle.ontimer(move, 5)

turtle.exitonclick()
```

Here we've turned control back over to the mainloop and the motion is on an event timer.  Other turtle events can execute so `exitonclick()` works.  Just something to think about going forward before you program yourself, and your turtle, into a corner.

Answer (score 1):

You should put
turtle.penup()
Before the while loop to make your code better and a little bit faster. It is almost a bug!

Answer (score 0):

You can bounce your wall, if you want to bounce it from upper wall, the screen width is 800 and length is 600

```
from turtle import turtle
turtle=Turtle()
    def move(self)://This will move your ball in diagonal direction
        x_dir=self.xcor()+self.x
        y_dir=self.ycor()+self.y
        self.goto(x_dir,y_dir)
    def bounce(self)://This will bounce back
        self.y *=-1
turtle.bounce()
```

This code is running because I did it with inheritance. You need to create a class then inherit all the properties and then create two methods there and then call those functions in the main class.